# How to pair Html elemens with lines of code in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, html, editor, vue.js, ace-editor

I'm programming interactive html editor using [Ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about)
 and [Vue Js](https://vuejs.org/). Code from Ace editor is automatically rendered as html preview using Vue. Now i would like to add interactions, such as click on rendered element should highlight exact line of code in Ace, where the code of selected element begins.

It would be easiest to handle if each rendred element would have attribute like `data-ace-line="47"` or `data-uid="B7a91Nmd"`, then i would store lines coresponding to each uniqueID somewhere.

Comment: I'm having the same question - have you found an answer for this since you have asked?

Comment: @sev3ryn Nope, I didn't found the answer. I decided to split the source code into smaller chunks and each chunk (editable widget) has it's unique ID. After the widget has to be edited i get it by it's ID and show only it's source code in Ace editor.